# Visual Basic Com Port doesn't Receive

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

I'm Trying to communicate with a com port using a visual basic console application.  The com port never receives data, and times out every time.  I've confirmed with a different program written in python that the com port and device are working correctly.  I am sure that I am just missing something since I am new to VB. I've tried opening the com port using two method, neither of which returned an error (the first method I used is commented out). Below is my script.

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Function ReceiveSerialData(ByVal data As String) As String
        ' Receive strings from a serial port. 
        Dim returnStr As String = ""
        Dim add As String = "Com6"
        'Dim port As New SerialPort("Com6", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One)
        Dim port As SerialPort = My.Computer.Ports.OpenSerialPort("COM6", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One)

        Try
            Dim state As Boolean = (port.IsOpen)
            If state = False Then
                Console.Write("Opening Port" + vbNewLine)
                port.Open()
            End If
            port.ReadTimeout = 5000
            port.Write("z")
            Dim cat As String = port.ReadLine()
        Catch ex As TimeoutException
            returnStr = "Error: Serial Port read timed out."
        Finally
            If port IsNot Nothing Then port.Close()
        End Try
        Console.Write(returnStr)
        Return returnStr
    End Function


    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Command for Telescope!:")
        Dim stdin As TextReader = Console.In
        Dim sInput As String = stdin.ReadLine
        Console.Write("Sending Command " + sInput + "." + vbNewLine)
        Dim sent As String
        sent = "z"
        Dim recv As String
        recv = ReceiveSerialData(sent)
        Console.Write(recv)

    End Sub



End Module
```

Comment: Your not using the [`DataReceived Event`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Just Call your `ReceiveSerialData` function on `DataRecieved` event and check.

Comment: I think I found the issue.  The sending device does not send a newline character so the program times out when I use readline, read existing works though